# Changing DefaultTask (Entry Point) in Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

According to Microsoft template the entry point of Windows Phone app is MainPage.xaml. I manage to change it to *.xaml page, but how to get rid of those .xaml pages and write only C#. In windows Forms it was quite easy, but what about Windows Phone ? If I just change the default task to be .cs file, it doesn't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in WinForms there is no concept of an application's main entry point not corresponding to a visual page represented by XAML (in this case, as you pointed out, the default is MainPage.xaml). The idea being that this wouldn't make sense since there always has to be a visual portion to a Phone application. While you could potentially write the same thing purely in code it's not something that is directly supported.

An application has the ability to run in the background via Background Agents (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx), but it still needs the visual portion of the application to install the Agent and to be accepted onto the Store.

Comment: I hoped that there would be some way to do it but.....
Thank you very much for answer

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Get rid of xaml files. I prefer write C#

Comment: Personally I find that to set up UI code  correctly results in a lot of hard to maintain code that XAML abstracts very nicely and nearly, by to achieve what you want, simply delete all XAML except for the Page itself and then fill in the rest with code.